# Can't copy and paste to Netbeans when accessed over RDC

Tags: remote-desktop, java, copy-paste, netbeans

I use Netbeans for development and I access it by using a Windows Remote Desktop Connection back to my workstation at HQ. This is a great set up except for one thing, I cannot copy text on my local machine and paste it into Netbeans. I can copy and paste into other applications.

Any ideas as to the cause?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Yea considered posting on SuperUser. Asked at SO since it was specific to Netbeans and no other application (even Java applications). Developers know NB better than sysops.

Comment: Just for the records. In a OSX single desktop environment, Netbeans doesn't catch the info from a Clipboard history manager I use. It gets stuck with the last item, I have to switch to another app, paste (yes, the item is already in memory), go back and paste.

Comment: Amending my previous comment: it's only a matter of switching to another app, go back to Netbeans and the history works. Seems that if we copy something inside it, it gets stuck with that clipboard item, the switch does the trick of updating its "memory".

Answer (score 1):

This may not work for you and I realize this is an OLD question, but my recent experience is that the following has worked the last few times I've had a problem* copying text from another application and pasting into Netbeans: I simply close whatever Chrome window(s) I have open, and the paste then works like a champ.

Windows XP, NetBeans IDE 7.1, Google Chrome 17.0.963.56

*symptom is that the paste does nothing. Pasting the same clipboard to applications other than NetBeans works fine.

Comment: Interesting. I use a Chrome variant (Rockmelt) so this could be my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I would RDP into my work computer to work in NetBeans and pasting would not work. I found a simple, although annoying, workaround: before pasting, switch to another application like Notepad or whatever you happen to have open, then switch back to NetBeans. That's all. You don't have to paste into the other app, just switch to it and switch back, then you'll get the current clipboard data... at least I do.

I also use Chrome but have not noticed that it makes a difference if it is open or not. Although if you close it before pasting, you have switched to another window and then the paste will work... but of course that will work if you close any other program.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of cross linking SU and NetBeans Bugzilla. Here are some bugs reports that I found.  My suggestion is to follow up with those bug reports.

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=180227

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=205697

Comment: I'm going to amend my comment here.  I just found that if I process kill rdpclip.exe I can copy from/into NetBeans again.